# Implementation of merge sort not working?

Tags: c, mergesort

My array is not sorted after running the code. What's wrong?

Result: 3,8,9,6,11,3,22,95.

I have tried long but all in vain.

```
   int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){
        int i;
        int my[]={3,11,19,22,8,9,13,95};
        msort(my,0,7);

        for(i=0;i<8;i++){
           printf("%d,",my[i]);
          }
       return 0;
 }

 int msort(int *ar,int low, int high){
       int mid;
       if(low<high){
          mid = (low+high)/2;

        msort(ar,low,mid);
        msort(ar,mid+1,high);
        merge(ar,low,mid,high);
     }
  }


int merge(int *ar,int low,int mid, int high){
//int ar[]={3,11,19,22};
//int ar2[]={8,9,13,95};
int temp[8];

int i,j,index,k;
k=0;
index=low;
i=low;
j=mid+1;
while(i<=mid && j<=high){
    if(ar[i]<ar[j]){
        temp[index++] = ar[i];
        i++;
    }else{
        temp[index++] = ar[j];
        j++;
    }
}
while(i<j){
    temp[index++] = ar[i];
    i++;

}
while(j<i){
    temp[index++] = ar[j];

    j++;
}

  //here i am updating my array with temp;

for(k=low;k<high;k++){
    ar[k]=temp[k];
}



  }
```

Comment: I can't stress enough how this gets easier if you just use a base pointer and length rather than a pointer, mid, and high. I.e., did you notice `ar` is *always* the same value? It doesn't have to be if you use *it* for the mid-point adjustments when recursing.

Comment: Read this article  http://www.dailyfreecode.com/code/merge-sort-2855.aspx

Comment: Regarding my prior comment, [see it live](http://ideone.com/ROO5tT). Apart from the pointer-usage, you may find copy-removal of the high-end of the merge interesting. If the low end finishes first, the remaining high end is already in place. It makes no sense to copy it to temp just to copy it back to the high end of the source array. Anyway, best of luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int merge(int *ar,int low,int mid, int high){
    int temp[8];

    int i,j,index,k;
    k=0;
    index=0;//temp's index start 0;
    i=low;
    j=mid+1;
    while(i<=mid && j<=high){
        if(ar[i]<ar[j]){
            temp[index++] = ar[i];
            i++;
        }else{
            temp[index++] = ar[j];
            j++;
        }
    }
    while(i<=mid){
        temp[index++] = ar[i];
        i++;
    }
    while(j<=high){
        temp[index++] = ar[j];
        j++;
    }

    for(k=low, index=0;k<=high;k++){//k include high
        ar[k]=temp[index++];
    }
}
```

Comment: pls explain this part                                            for(k=low, index=0;k<=high;k++){//k include high
        ar[k]=temp[index++];
    }

Comment: @raton `k<high` --> `k<=high`, because `high` is included in the sorted range. I think of the index of the `temp` was in from 0's that it is easy to understand general purpose.(You will need to be modified to ensure it is not the size of the future original sequence.)

Answer (score 2):

your while conditions are off, need to empty the arrays `while (j<i)` is never true.

```
while (i <= mid) { 
    temp[index++] = ar[i];
    i++;
}

while (j <= high) {
    temp[index++] = ar[j];
    j++;
}
```